# What's the need of iterator in JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, iterator, ecmascript-6

Recently I became aware of **ES6 iterator** went to the help of JS arrays.
I searched about it but still confused about its philosophy of design,
because other methods was still OK.

On the other hand I've been told not to use it!

```
var arr = ['w', 'y', 'k', 'o', 'p'];
var eArr = arr[Symbol.iterator]();

// your browser must support for..of loop
// and let-scoped variables in for loops

for (let letter of eArr) {
  console.log(letter);
}
```

Was it just because of *`for..of`* support?

Of course, this feature hasn't been added to JS objects.

Comment: iterators are used for `for/of` and for generators.  The whole concept of having lots of types (Array, Set, Map, spread syntax, rest syntax, any generator) that can all be iterated exactly the same way is really, really useful.  It creates a generic mechanism that lots of things can use without having to design a new mechanism for every type.

Comment: For example, the constructor for the `Set` object accepts any iterable as an argument.  What that means technically is that any object that supports the `[Symbol.iterator]` contract can be passed there without the code the `Set` object having to know anything other than how to do a generic iteration.  Very useful.

Comment: Thanks, But why the community behind this trend(at least Stackoverflow questions and answer) do suggest not to use it?

Comment: Plus, you can now make any object type work with `for/of` and you can make it work any way you want by just creating an appropriate iterator or even multiple different iterators for your object.

Comment: If you are running in an environment where ES6 iterators are universally supported (such as recent versions of node.js or transpiling), then I've only seen recommendations to use iterators, not seen any recommendations to avoid them.  For example, there's pretty much no reason to use `.forEach()` any more for iterating because `for/of` is simply better (provides more looping control without an extra function call and can be better optimized).

Comment: Yes, Indeed `forEach` does not have breaking ability which `for in` has!

Comment: @jfriend00, is it true that `for...of` is always better optimised? I have seen very good performance with `.forEach` (or `.some`, and the likes), where the optimisation seemed to work very well.

Comment: @trincot - I know of no reason to use `.forEach()` any more in an ES6 world.  You simply get better control with `for/of`.  I don't know how much various interpreters have taken advantage of optimizing `for/of`, but it should have greater opportunities for optimization because the looping is entirely in the interpreter's control, whereas with .`forEach()` there's a method that is in control, not the interpreter.  I use `for/of` because I have better looping control and `forEach()` offers nothing that `for/of` doesn't already have.

Comment: Still I like `.map`, `.reduce`, `.some`, ... etc over `for ...of` because of their *functional programming* nature, often giving an opportunity to save on variable assignments and mutations.

Comment: @trincot - `.map()` and `.reduce()` have functionality that `for/of` does not try to replace.  I haven't seen anyone advocating abandoning them.

Comment: True, (I was not trying to contradict you ;-) )

Comment: @jfriend00 you don't get the index with `for..of`. `.forEach(doSomething)` is much more concise than a clunky `for (let item of items) { doSomething(item); }`. `for..of` calls a function as well: `next()`. Multiple times. I wonder where you see _"opportunities for optimization"_. Or how the interpreter can be in control, when in fact it has to follow a protocol. And even if you think the interpreter is in control, then how does that give **you** _"better looping control"_ at the same time?

Comment: @zeroflagL - If you want to get the index, you can with: `for (let [index, value] of arr.entries())` and then you have both index and value just like with `.forEach()`.

Comment: @zeroflagL - You get better looping control with `for/of` vs. `.forEach()` because with for/of, you can break out of the loop at any time or even return from the parent function.  You can't do either for `.forEach()`.  Basically, there's no way to terminate `.forEach()` early - that has always been a limitation of its design.

Comment: @jfriend00 good points! I like the combo `entries()` / destructuring. If need to break out of a loop, then a for loop might not be the best choice in the first place. And, well, it's called `forEach`, and not `doUntil` or `doWhile`. Streams provide that functionality. Unfortunately JS doesn't offer a native implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons for introducing symbols like `[Symbol.iterator]` include that it allows one to define it also for custom objects, and so make them available for `for ... of`, spread syntax, and other constructs that can be used with iterables.

And as this possibility was made available, it was only logical to also implement it that way for standard objects that were to expose iterable behaviour, like arrays. This makes it all the more consistent: both standard and custom objects will now expose the iterable capability if, and only when, they define `[Symbol.iterator]`.

Now methods (e.g. [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) and constructors (e.g. [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)) become available which only require an iterable to be passed to them, which *can* be an array, but doesn't *have* to be. This opens up possibilities of lose coupling, where different libraries may even communicate based on this [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol).